# Copy vector - vector

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
vector<vector<int>> tranches_max(vector<vector<int>> x)
{
   vector<vector<int>> y;
   y[0].swap(x[0]);
   return y;
}
int main() {

vector<vector<int>> x=
{
      {2, 1, 0, 2},
      {0, 1, 0, 3},
      {1, 3, 0, 0},
      {0, 2, 2, 0},
    };
  for (vector< vector<int> >::size_type u = 0; u < x.size(); u++) 
     { for (vector<int>::size_type v = 0; v < x[u].size(); v++) 
       { cout << x[u][v] << " ";
       }
       cout <<endl;
     }
 vector<vector<int>> y= tranches_max(x);    
 for (vector< vector<int> >::size_type u = 0; u < y.size(); u++) 
 { for (vector<int>::size_type v = 0; v < y[u].size(); v++) 
{ cout << y[u][v] << " ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

My code does not generate an error, but it crashes ..
I think the copy is the problem ..
Do you have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: `y[0]` is not valid, since `y` is empty.

Comment: In `tranches_max`, you access the first element of `y` (`y[0]`), while it is empty; that is an error.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you try to do, but in your function `tranches_max` you access the element `y[0]` which is out of bounds for the vector `y`. You construct y with the empty constructor making the vector empty. Maybe you need to create y with some initial size?

Answer (score 0):

1. Y is empty
2. This code should not compile as there is no space between >> which makes it stream operator

Comment: C++ Standard does not require a space between >>.

Comment: OP is also using the initilization that was only introduced in c++11. Apparently he is using c++11 and there you don't need the space. (not the one to downvote btw).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it does for prior c++11